# Firestore query by date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am tring to query to a Firestore database to a collection and filter by date. I have a Timestamp field (dateStart) and i need to get the results have date today , i don't care about time ,i tried to use this but it works only have same time

My document : 20 septembre 2021 at 01:30:00 UTC+1

```
refWallet
  .where("dateStart", "==", new Date("2021,09,20"))
  .get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a range query with start and end points to cover the intended time.  In Firestore, timestamp types are always considered a single point in time and do not have date and time components available.  It's the same for Date objects in JavaScript.

```
refWallet
  .where("dateStart", ">=", startDate)
  .where("dateStart", "<", endDate)
  .get()
```

If this is not what you want, then you probably shouldn't use a timestamp type field and instead use a string that will give you an exact match.  For example, you could store dates as strings formatted YYYYMMDD in order to query for exact dates without ranges.

Comment: i make this colRef = query(colRef, 
                where("createdDate", ">=", q1), 
                where("createdDate", "<", q2)) but still not works

Comment: @NandaZ did you ever get your query to work? My date range lookup doesn't work using query() either.